# Return image from WCF web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have created my first WCF webservice and I am trying to return an image from it based on some passed parameters.  I am getting the error:

> **The content type image/jpeg of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.**

What do I need to do to resolve this issue?

The web.config file of my website that is calling the service has the following config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRestImageService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:59473/RestImageService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRestImageService"
    contract="RestImageService.IRestImageService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IRestImageService" />
</client>
```

The webservice web.config looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

The Service Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "Image/{type}/{typeid}/{imageid}/{size}/{extension}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Stream Image(string type, string typeid, string imageid, string size = "lrg", string extension = "jpg");
```

I am very new at WCF, so any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**
After implementing Tim's suggestion, I am getting a new error:

> **There was no endpoint listening at localhost:59473/RestImageService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.**

I am not sure how to configure the web service to fix this issues.  Any suggestions?

This is how I'm accessing the web service:

```
RestImageServiceClient client = new RestImageServiceClient();
    client.Image(WSC.Common.BO.User.User.ImageFolder.Buyer, "27085", "BuyerPhoto", "LRG", "jpg");
```

I hope to be able to set the src tag of my image to the web service url once I get it working.

Comment: Are you using SOAP or REST?

Comment: Your binding protocols don't match.

Comment: @GrantThomas I have googled around but I am not sure how to make the binding protocols match.  Can you give me pointers?

Comment: @Tim I'm attempting to make a RESTful webservice.

Comment: I changed the protocolMapping to <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>.  Same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basicHttpBinding` is SOAP (version 1.1).  To enable REST-based services, I believe (haven't done much of it myself) that you need to use the `webHttpBinding`.

I would try something like this.  In your service's config file, make the following changes:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

This *should* configure your default binding to be `webHttpBinding` for `http` calls.

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The above code *should* add a default endpoint behavior for `webHttp`.

Finally, in your client config file, make the following change:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:59473/RestImageService.svc"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="RestImageService.IRestImageService" 
            name="WebHttpBinding_IRestImageService" />
</client>
```

I can't say for certain that this will work, but I've done a lot with WCF (on the SOAP side), so I think this will at least get you pointed in the right direction.

**EDIT**

`RestImageServiceClient` is a SOAP client. To use a REST service, you need to use an HTTP API.  Here's an example from [WCF REST Service with JSON]http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327420/WCF-REST-Service-with-JSON):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] data = client.DownloadData("http://localhost:11523/Service1.svc/GetData");
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);

DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string));
string result = obj.ReadObject(stream).ToString();
```

I recommend googling "WCF REST JSON Client exmaple" - you'll get lots of hits and a few different ways to do this.

As an added note, you **could** make a SOAP call with your SOAP client, as long as you have a SOAP endpoint exposed on the service.

Comment: The result of this is a new error: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:59473/RestImageService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: How are you trying to call the service in your code?  Can you edit your question with the code you're using?  It sounds like you're trying to use a proxy (client), and that's a SOAP approach, not REST.

Comment: See my edit to my answer - the key here is that clients for REST and SOAP are different. SOAP uses a proxy, where as REST will use an HTTP API of some sort.